# how to get current terminal color pair in bash

Tags: bash, ansi-colors

I would like to query and store the current terminal color pair in BASH e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

#some ANSI colour escape sequences
red="\033[0;31m"
grn="\033[0;32m"
blu="\033[0;34m"

def="\033[0;00m" # default

echo -e "Change to ${red} red to ${def} default to ${blu} blue."

# now store the current color (which happens to be blue) e.g.:

cur=????

echo -e "Change to ${grn} green and back to what I had before ${cur}"
echo -e "This would be in blue if variable cur contained e.g.: 0;34m."
echo -e "Back to default${def}"
exit 0
```

The answer that eludes me is how to capture the current color

```
cur=????
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question was about the current *color*, not the cursor *position*.

Both are "nonstandard" (though the latter, cursor position report is implemented by anything which has a valid claim to "VT100 emulator").

However, xterm implements a set of escape sequences referred to as *dynamic colors*, which predate the ANSI color functionality.  Those set the working colors including text foreground and background.  I modified this in [2002](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_168) to allow an application to send the sequence with a "?" rather than a color to tell xterm to return the color value, e.g.,

```
OSC 1 1 ? ST
```

using the notation given in [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)

Comment: For anyone wondering, the equivalent to `OSC 1 1 ? ST` in a VT100-compabilble terminal is this Bash command: `printf '\033]11;?\033\'`.

Answer (score 9):

You can't; there is no standard control sequence to report the current cursor attributes.

What *does* exist, however, is a sequence to save and restore the current cursor position and attributes:

- `\e7` (DECSC) will save the cursor position and attributes.
- `\e8` (DECRC) will restore the saved cursor position and attributes.

There is no standard way to restore *only* the cursor attributes; however, as rici mentioned, you can get a report of the current position using `\e[6n` (DSR), then use the response to manually "un-restore" the cursor position after restoring its position and attributes.

Again, though, it's probably easier (and better) to just keep track of the colors in your application, rather than making the terminal responsible for that.

Answer (score 5):

It's important to understand that the terminal state has *nothing to do with bash*. Bash doesn't care. It simply reads from `stdin` and writes to `stdout` and `stderr`. (See Note 1)

All terminal effects are implemented by the terminal emulator you happen to be using, of which there are many. In a graphical environment, you might be using, for example, `xterm` or `konsole`. You'll need to search the documentation for those emulators for specific terminal control codes which they interpret.

As far as I know, there is no standard code to get a report of the current terminal state, other than the cursor position (<kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>).

So your best bet is to remember the changes you made when you make them.

You can find a list of the standard codes implemented by the Linux console using `man console_codes` (although few people use the Linux console these days); most of those are also interpreted by `xterm` and other graphical consoles. There's an list of `xterm` sequences in Thomas Dickey's [xterm site](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html); it's a more or less de facto standard for terminal emulators but, as I said, you'll need to search in each emulator's documentation for idiosyncratic control sequences.

#### Notes

1. In interactive mode, `bash` uses a library called `readline` to help it handle some terminal effects. In particular, `readline` tries to maintain the current console cursor position, although it is easy to fool it. In `PS1` you need to surround console control sequences with `\[` and `\]` precisely because `readline` does not know that they are control sequences.

Comment: many thanks; it seems rather odd. It must be stored _somewhere_ or other. I had thought perhaps in the $PS1 prompt string.

Comment: @ubundom: I repeat, it has *nothing to do with bash*. The terminal emulator obviously maintains state, but it does not have a way to report it. Bash doesn't care. It just sends to stdout whatever bytes you tell it to send.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood, is that u are asking to to get the default profile color of the user, of which u have change color of!

Eg: User is using '***Bright Green** font color on **Black** background*', you change it to '***Red** font color on **White** background*'. Now how to get/know the default colors and set them back to it!

---

You can use the sequence `\033[0m` in *bash* [also for *command prompt* (batch scripting) / *powershell* (ps scripting)]