# Powershell: Get the background color of the Windows Terminal

Tags: powershell, background-color, windows-terminal

I use ANSI colors in a Powershell script under Windows 11. In order to adapt the background color of the font to the current background color of the terminal, I would like to read out this Windows terminal background color.
However, all methods I know of only return the "default color", which is not correct.

Terminal is set to "Campbell Powershell" color scheme (blue background).

The terminal settings are stored in a JSON file under "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json". I could extract the settings there. But it would be easier if someone knew a simpler way to get the terminal background color in Powershell.

I tried:

```
PS C:\> $Host.ui.RawUI.BackgroundColor
Black

PS C:\> [console]::BackgroundColor
Black
```

Both commands return Black, which is the scheme but not the color!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to give a negative answer here, but sometimes one is warranted when the data supports it.

*Short answer:*  This is not yet available in Windows Terminal.  There is a [feature request (#3178)](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3718) for it that has been (according to the Windows Terminal team) fairly low on the backlog for a while now.

---

*Longer explanation:*

When your script uses ANSI escape codes to set the colors, those take effect on Windows Terminal.  However, the `$Host.ui` settings are for PowerShell itself and are separate from the Windows Terminal values.

As a result, what we need is a way to programmatically read the *current* Windows Terminal ANSI color code settings.  Unfortunately, that's not yet available.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28334701/11810933) mentions the method for doing so in xterm, and those codes are implemented in [quite a few terminal emulators](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3718#issuecomment-690486349), but (from the parent issue of that comment) [not yet in Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3718) (issue #3718).

I doubt that reading the JSON settings is going to help in this case, since that's not going to represent the current *state* of the terminal based on the ANSI escape codes you've set.

I'd love to offer you some other workaround, but I wasn't able to come up with one in a few tries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had already feared that.
But it's not a problem. I extract the background color from the JSON file, which is sufficient for my task.
Another method would have been more elegant, but that's how it works :-D
Thanks!